# Diy ac topping up

Tags: ac, air

I've never bought refrigerant before. So my question is: are refil ac bottles single use or can I  get several topups from them?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, as soon as you puncture the can of refrigerant (in most use cases), it will tend to leak. Over time, whatever isn't used in the can will bleed out to atmosphere and that'll be that. For this reason, I consider them one use.

On a side note, if you aren't sure of how to *properly* check your refrigerant levels, it is highly recommended you take it somewhere to have it serviced properly. If your AC system is working correctly in the first place, it shouldn't need a "top up". Overfilling an AC system can be as bad or worse than a system with too little refrigerant in it. It can cause blown out seals and possibly even the destruction of the compressor. None of which is a "cheap" fix.

Comment: I've never looked over the shoulder at someone servicing AC on a car, but I have on a house AC system.  House AC tradesmen use a tank that can be used several times and are very careful to not leak refrigerant into the atmosphere.  Do mechanics have a similar rig?

Comment: @Flydog57 - If they are a full up A/C shop, yes, they'll have pretty much the same sized bottle of refrigerant they use to refill an auto A/C system as what you've seen for the home A/C system (just a different refrigerant). They also have machines which recover the refrigerant as well. These types of machines and bottles don't leak refrigerant between usage. Home use refrigerant refill cans are a far cry from these professional grade machines.